# Probability of two balls to be red from a random experiment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose I have a bag. It contains 2 red balls and 5 blue balls.

If I draw two balls from the bag consecutively, with replacement, the possible outcomes of this experiment can be :- {RR,RB,BR,BB}, where **R is the event of getting red ball** and **B is the event of getting blue ball.**

So the probability of both drawn balls being red can be :

**P(x)=n(x)/n(S)**...where x represents the event, in which both drawn balls are red.

So, *P(x)=1/4 ...........(1)*

But, I found that, P(X)=P(R intersection B), as R and B event happening simultaneously.

So, *P(X) becomes 4/49 .......(2)*

*In my 1st approach, I am considering the event of both balls being red and it is same in my 2nd approch also*

**Although, there is a huge discrimancy in the probability, between my two approaches**

Why is this happening and which approach should I use??

Comment: Probability being given by $n(x)/n(S)$ is the general formula **only** when you know for certain that the outcomes are equally likely to occur.  Consider a bag with a million red balls and one blue ball... and you draw only a single ball.  You should know from example that the probability of drawing a red ball here (*assuming all balls equally likely to be drawn*) is $\frac{1000000}{1000001}$... not $\frac{1}{2}$.  The jump to two balls being drawn should not have had you suddenly ignore this.  There are two outcomes to playing the lottery, win or lose.  You don't win with probability 1/2.

Comment: In scenarios like this, it can be helpful to *imagine* that the balls are all uniquely labeled.  In doing so, each of the $49$ outcomes of sequences of two *labeled* balls being pulled are seen to be equally likely outcomes and then we can use counting techniques.